Battery Status Changing after some delay after the healthd updates
Did anyone resolved the issue of the battery status as Charging and Discharging in the GUI.
In my kernel the Charging and Discharging is happening perfectly.
logs from the kernel:-
phyboard_polis:/ # cat /sys/class/power_supply/ltc4155-battery/status
Charging phyboard_polis:/ # cat /sys/class/power_supply/ltc4155-battery/status
Discharging
but while i am updating the same in the hal as : vendor/nxp-opensource/imx/health/health.cpp in the method HealthImpl::UpdateHealthInfo
the updation of the status is happening quite delay may be for 30sec time .
Any idea how to reslove the issue to upadte the battery status immediately just after the kernel updates the status?
